# Is it ok to have 2 screen recorders running at the same time?

Tags: 12.04, ffmpeg, kazam

Ok I always have issues recording my desktop with `kazam` or `gtk-recordmydesktop` so now I'm very paranoid so is it ok to have `ffmpeg` running with `kazam` at the same time? will there be conflicts? thanks

Comment: I don't think there would be big trouble.. but the only way to find out is to try.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` isn't a recorder, it's a transcoder. It's turning what you're recording into a compressed, playable video file. It's likely that one of your screen recorders is calling it.

But otherwise, screen recorders use up a incredible percentage of CPU resources. If you were actually recording with two of them at once, you would likely be unable to use your desktop, so I guess that would be a pretty severe issue.

But I don't think there would be any actual conflicts. The graphics stack is quite modular.

Having two *installed* (but not running together) should certainly not be an issue.

Comment: ffmpeg can capture the screen via x11grab, so calling ffmpeg a "screen recorder" isn't an inaccurate description.